# C++ - Allocating Larger Array on the Heap

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, heap-memory, stack-memory

I downloaded Visual Studio and started C++ yesterday. I have now run in to a problem though. I have a super simple program that fills a large array with booleans and then counts the number of true elements. I now want to run my program for extremely large arrays (lengths of 2^33 or 2^34 preferably). I have understood that this will generate a problem with the stack overflowing and that I should allocate the array on the heap instead. I do not understand how to do this though. I have also heard that it is customary to use vectors instead of arrays but I figured that these might be slower so I stuck to arrays. What do I do to make my program run as fast as possible for large array lengths?

```
void makeB(bool *a, long double length)
{
    for (long x = 0; x < sqrtl(length/2)+1; ++x)
    {
        for (long y = x; y < sqrtl(length)+1; ++y)
        {
            long int z = x * x + y * y;
            if (z < length)
            {
                a[z] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const long length = 268435457;
    static bool a[length] = {};
    long b = 0;
    makeB(a, length);
    for (long i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i])
        {
            b += 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld: ", length - 1);
    printf("%ld.\n", b);

    char input;
    cin >> input;
    return 0;
}
```

To clarify I want to be able to increase the length variable to larger values without getting a Stack Overflow error. Fast code is also preferrable. I m also fine with using vectors if that truly is better. If it will make the cause of my confusion clearer I come from Java.

Thanks!

EDIT: First I need to point out that indeed 2^40 is way too much to expect from my system as pointed out by almost everyone, sorry about that. I feel that I could expect maybe 2^33. And secondly thanks for all the answers but what is the final consensus? Should I have a look at std::make_unique? Thanks again!

Comment: What your are looking for is the keyword `new`. I recommend reading a bit about C++ and then returning to this problem, as you seem to lack some basics.

Comment: @JeromeReinländer Please stop teaching `new` to beginners already; we'll never get rid of it that way.

Comment: Do you seriously have a terabyte of memory?

Comment: @JeromeReinländer I do indeed lack a lot of basics. I have tried using new to allocate the array on the heap though and it did not work out for me.

Comment: 2^40 bools still take up at least 2^40 bits ~ 137 GB, or 1.1TB if stored in a plain array. Do you have that much RAM installed?

Comment: Don't use `new`. It's the old way to allocate memory, it's error-prone. Prefer either `std::make_unique` or better yet, simply use containers like `std::vector` and let them handle the details.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'd hope that the OS would start swapping ... (although I don't disagree it'll either kill the life of the SSD or grind to a halt)

Comment: @UKMonkey I certainly have not set up that much swap space either, the program would receive a nice SIGKILL.

Comment: @BaummitAugen 2^40 might have been a bit optimistic. I have edited my question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @IvarEriksson 2^35 bools are still ~35GB of RAM, so you probably still don't want an array. Bit-compressed it's 4.3GB, so that sounds more manageable for normal PCs. (Ok, after the edit, at least bit-compressed representation is quite feasible.)

Comment: Your array keeps shrinking with each edit. Have you done any actual estimates of the size you need or are you just making stuff up?

Comment: @IvarEriksson BaummitAugen was right, don't start on `new`. Learn the modern alternative (`std::make_unique`) first.

Comment: @BaummitAugen when you say a nice SIGKILL, do you mean `nice -n -20 kill -9`?  ;)

Comment: @AndrewKashpur  Isn't that sorted out by the if statement? But a break in an else-block would be good.

Comment: Make sure to compile your program for 64-bit and not 32-bit.

Comment: *"And secondly thanks for all the answers but what is the final consensus?"* For simple counting `std::vector<bool>` will do. It even compresses the bools into bits for you.